# Reuse CIFilter for stacking new images on top of a single one

Tags: ios, swift, core-graphics, paint, core-image

So I'm trying to make a simple drawing app with the use of CoreImage.

I plan is to have a base image, then on `touchesMoved` record a position of the finger, based on the recorded positions stroke a path with Core Graphics, blur it (to have a "brush hardness" effect) and finally stack the result on top of a base image.

So for staking I have a `stackingFilter` which is a `CIFilter`, then I initialize it

```
stackingFilter.setValue(baseImage, forKey: kCIInputBackgroundImageKey)
```

and in `touchesMoved` I use

```
stackingFilter.setValue(self.imageForPoints(points), forKey: kCIInputImageKey)
```

Finally I use CIImageAccumulator to get a real image and display it. But the problem is that when I draw, my line "thickens" and I suspect that the cause is that instead of stacking a new image on top of the base one it stacks it on top of the previous one.

How can I make the filter to stack on the base image only?